# Enable swipe gesture in FlipView control

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps, swipe, flipview

I am using a FlipView control in my windows store app. The swipe gesture is not working for the FlipView control. I want to hide the next and previous buttons and show the previous and next items only on swipe. I am running the app on simulator. By customizing the default style I am able to hide the buttons of the FlipView control, but the swipe is not recognized in the simulator. Do I need to change the properties to enable swipe in the FlipView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The buttons should hide and the swipe gesture should be detected when the touch mode of the simulator is used. The buttons are shown when the mouse pointer is used.